# Testing accessibility with cypress-axe

Tags: accessibility, cypress

[image: cypress-a11y-test][image]I am trying to integrate the cypress-axe [package](https://github.com/avanslaars/cypress-axe) in my project . After installing cypress-axe and axe-core libraries . I have imported **cypress-axe** in *cypress\support\index.js* as below :

```
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
import './commands'
import 'cypress-axe'

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})

Cypress.on('window:before:unload', e => {
  const coverage = e.currentTarget.__coverage__;

  if (coverage) {
    map.merge(coverage);
  }
});
```

In the spec file , injcted axe as below:

```
    before(() => {
        cy.visit(url);
        cy.injectAxe();
    });

    describe('Initial state of component', () => {
        it('Has no detectable a11y violations on load', () => {
            // Test the page at initial load
            cy.checkA11y()
        })
     })
```

But when I run cypress tests , I get error *cy.injectAxe() is not a function*.[image: cypress-axe error]

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I used your example and everything works. See this repo for a small example: https://github.com/gabbersepp/cypress-example/tree/stackoverflow-59355872

Comment: @Josef thanks for your example , I was missing support file in cypress.json config file . After that I am getting error *ArrayIterator* is not defined. Console error added in question

Comment: Can you try to reduce this problem to a few lines of code? This seems to be a problem with your setup. I made some research and it seems that axa includes a polyfill to provide cross browser support. Maybe you use my example and extend it with your setup until it fails? Or you provide a public example of your failing project so the community can have a look at it.

Comment: @JosefBiehler you were right , my project was including a polyfill  for @@iterator  protototype, sourced from https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-library/blob/master/polyfills/DOMTokenList/prototype/%40%40iterator/polyfill.js , some how cypress runner was calling this polyfill and ArrayIterator not defined error was coming up

Comment: if (
  'Symbol' in this &&
  'iterator' in this.Symbol &&
  !!document.createElement('div').classList[Symbol.iterator]
 ) {

  DOMTokenList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
   return new ArrayIterator(this);
  };
 }

Comment: After commenting the polyfill , cypress -axe is running but don't get any meaningful a11y violation error . Image attached above

Comment: Axe is calling the polyfill, not cypress ;-) Unfortunatelly I have never worked with Axe so I can not help with with the Axe part :-( What would you expect to be shown? Maybe I find some time to play around with it.

Comment: btw there is an official example using axe I think: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes